# How to get Public Instagram User Posts with React?

Tags: reactjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I have a REACT application, it is a portfolio site for a children's fashion store, I want to link the instagram posts on the site.
The store's Instagram is a public instagram.
In the old days I could easily get everything related to a particular instagram profile using the URL https://www.instagram.com/nameOfPublicUser/?a__=1
Today I get a Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) error where the API call is not allowed.
Reading the developers.facebook.com documentation, they tell me to use the GraphAPI.

Reading the [GRAPHAPI](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) documentation, it informs us that it is necessary to get access tokens to be able to use the GraphAPI.

Reading the [ACCESS TOKEN](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/access-tokens/) documentation, in order to perform queries to the graphAPI we must have the permission of the user that is accessing our application, i.e., my brochure site. From the moment he logs in we need to get his authorization, and we do this through Facebook Login.

Reading the [FACEBOOK LOGIN](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/) documentation, we must "register" our app at developers.facebook.com and implement the Facebook SDK for Javascript.

Anyway, so much work to just pull PUBLIC data from a PUBLIC profile to display on my site.
Is there an easy call API to bring up the POSTS from a public instagram profile?

Comment: I edited my answer with a possible implementation using Selenium.